# Why load images from different domain?

Tags: web-performance, web-architecture

I have learned that browsers can only load a few files from the same domain at the same time. Therefore you should place your images on a different domain, or on a subdomain, to speed up page performance. Something like that...

**Is it worth building websites like this, or will browsers change this function soon? Or maybe they already have?**

**Or maybe better asked: Will it soon become unnecessary to load your images from other domains for page performance?**

The websites I am building now will not have their images hosted on a CDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser limits the concurrent HTTP connections to a single server for the server's sake.  While the limits have been increased in [most browsers](http://meronymy.blogspot.com/2011/09/overview-of-browser-concurrent.html) over time, there will always be limitations in web development and if you're a serious web developer you should suck it up and adopt the current best practices for working within them.

Without hosting your images on a CDN you can reduce the number of requests by [combining your images into CSS sprites](https://web.archive.org/web/20111119015314/http://exceller.info/optimizing-webpage-load-time-by-using-css-sprites-and-suturing/) (archived) when appropriate.  Check out the logo on StackOverflow, for example :)

Also, combine your CSS and Javascript into single files for production deployments.

Answer (score 3):

A second reason that you might do this: if the images are being provided by users (avatar uploads e.g.), then you should host these from a separate domain to avoid any javascript that might be injected from having access to user cookies on your main application domain.

From what I understand this is a *little* esoteric, but there are some [proofs of concept](http://iamajin.blogspot.com/2014/11/when-gifs-serve-javascript.html), and [this is why Google uses a separate domain](https://security.googleblog.com/2012/08/content-hosting-for-modern-web.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subdomain like `static.example.com` to serve static files like images and videos. The advantage of such a usage will be on server side where you serve `static.example.com` from a fast server like nginx while keeping the `example.com` proxied to apache. As a result of this client will be able to download these static resources faster since they are served faster.